# A parameter of constructor is "constants", is there a design-pattern / elegant solution?

Tags: php, constructor, hardcode, flexibility

This is mostly an imaginary problem, no real life situation, but it's simply do depict with.
In this example we cache a point to a directory. I used to have

common.php

```
define('PATH_TO_CACHE', '/var/www/cache');
```

pixel.php

```
class Pixel
{
    private int $x, $y;

    public function __construct(int $x, int $y)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        // drawing...
        file_put_contents(PATH_TO_CACHE.'/test.php', var_export([$this->x, $this->y], true));
    }
}

$a = new Pixel(1,4);
$b = new Pixel(4,1);
$c = new Pixel(1,1);
```

this is so far very simple, but that way it's not so flexible, our code is tight to `PATH_TO_CACHE`.
After refactoring:

```
class Pixel
{
    private readonly int $x, $y;
    private readonly string $pathToCache;

    public function __construct(int $x, int $y, string $pathToCache)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
        $this->pathToCache = $pathToCache;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        // drawing...
        file_put_contents($this->pathToCache.'/test.php', var_export([$this->x, $this->y], true));
    }
}
```

this is then fully independent now, but how do we instantiate Pixel?

```
$a = new Pixel(1,4, '/var/www/cache');
$b = new Pixel(4,1, '/var/www/cache');
$c = new Pixel(1,1, '/var/www/cache');
```

now let me not summarize why it is bad, starting out from redundancy nightmare.
But I cant figure a real solution. How to do it? And let's try keep this object immutable. And `Pixel` itself cant have that constants, since what if this `Pixel` can be reused among totally different projects?

Comment: I would implement it as a simple base `Pixel` class, and then extend that with `CachedPixel` that also accepts a [PSR-6](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-6/) compatible caching object as part of the constructor. The cache object itself then contains any necessary configuration. Also I would _strongly_ suggest not using the `final` keyword unless you have exceedingly good reasons to not allow a class to be extended. The same, but to a lesser extent, for the `private` keyword.

Comment: I misused the "final", I meant "readonly"